# i need my function that skips array items to return to first item if the the array is over

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have this function that skips array items in a predetermined fashion to be able to loop itself for example if i tell it to jump two times from the last item in the array i need it to be able to jump two items ahead and land on the first item in that array
here it is:

```
 function skip (start, pattern, arr)
   {
    let idx = 0,
    res = [ ];

    pattern.unshift (start); 

    for (let i of pattern) {
        idx += i;
        res.push (arr [idx]);
    }

    return res;
}
```

for clarification sake if i say:

```
skip (0, [ 1,1,2,1 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

I need it to return [1,2,3,1,2]. does anybody know a way to achieve that???

Comment: 2 items from the last is not ending up on the first but the second item if you go full circle. Where does the reset to the first item come from and how is it determined?

Comment: sorry i meant the item with the first index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [reminder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) (modulo) with the length of the array and adjust the index for the access.

```js
function skip(start, pattern, arr) {
    let idx = 0,
        res = [];

    pattern.unshift(start);
    for (let i of pattern) {
        idx += i;
        res.push(arr[idx % arr.length]);
    }
    return res;
}

console.log(skip(0, [1, 1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4]));
```